# What's the best way to stop users re-booking tickets...?

Tags: php

So, I am making a ticket booking system for a friend who is running a Drama production show for his school.

They preferably don't want users to pay online but rather them book tickets and then pay when they are at the show.

My idea is to send a confirmation email once they have booked and then when they confirm their email set a session variable so they can't constantly rebook (as there would be an issue with spam bookings).

Something like:

```
$_SESSION['alreadyBooked'] = 'booked';
```

So what I am asking is, could there be a better way of restricting users from rebooking over and over or even better only allowing them one booking per 24 hours? Bearing in mind that the users are not registered and it is a guest only booking.

Comment: Move to another browser, incognito/in private session, and/or clear the site's cookies, you're hosed. I would say given your requirements, it would not be possible to prevent multiple bookings, only to annoy or perturb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could let them provide email address, and send a confirmation email with activation code. If they fake their email, they won't receive the code.

I have also done this with user's phone number by sending activation code in text message (by twillo API or nexmo API). This way will cost some money, but it can provide more restrictions since it not likely one will have two cell phone numbers.

Comment: They key is the activation code. If you cannot provide a valid activation code, you won't book the ticket.

Comment: The email one can be easily bypassed with a fake email generator. Using a phone number is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use their student id as a login to book tickets that way the school can know who is booking tickets and who is double booking.

Comment: Couldn't someone just use someone elses id to spam the system?

Comment: Of course they can. there would have to be a password as well, to keep that from happening. But if the ID and password got out and was given to someone else to keep booking, that kid can get in trouble or questioned about it if it was that big of a deal:-P

Comment: The last line of the question states this isn't an option, given the requirements. There's also an assumption the OP can access the authentication system of the school, which is entirely likely it's not possible.

Comment: Agh, I looked over that:-/ and the people cannot pay over the Internet...? Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your registration requirements but I would suggest validating each registration with their email address, once a registration has been confirmed... you set it in your DB and then validate every new registration's email address before confirmation.

Comment: *Bearing in mind that the **users are not registered** and it is a guest only booking.*

Comment: Yes, you can still compare/check the email address, can't you?

Comment: Perhaps the only improvement would be to save the date/time of the last booking in a table and use that to look up if the email is allowed to reserve tickets (based on how long between now and then). That would be "better" than a session variable; creating or using other email addresses is fairly trivial, though. Still pretty flimsy.

Comment: They could use multiple email addresses, but they could put in their student ID along with email address. You would not have to have usernames, registration, or anything like access to the school database